# Are Google persistent cloud anchors working when using Android emulator?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to develop an AR Android Application with Kotlin, using ARCore Google Persistent Cloud Anchors, along with sceneform, in order to place 3D models in several geographical locations. The requirement for using persistent cloud anchors according to [this guide here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/quickstart), is to associate my Android app with an Oath 2.0 client ID, which is generated from Google Cloud Platform by providing the application Id from AndroidManifest.xml of my app and my SHA-1 fingerprint. Both of these were configured properly, the API in Google Cloud Platform is enabled as supposed to be, so I'm wondering if the issue is that I'm trying to run the app using an Android emulator.

Has anyone tried using persistent cloud anchors on an emulator?
Is there any other solution available, except for bying a new device?

I'm using:

*Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4

ARCore version 1.29

sceneform-ux:1.17.1*